# Set all Labels Font before opening the Form

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, label

Before opening the form I used following code to check if its label then change the font

```
foreach (Label ctl in frm.Controls)
{
    ctl.Font = usefontgrid;
}
```

But on first line return error because it check other control types such as textbox or button,etc.

How can I check if the object is only label then go to for each?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this;

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c is Label)
        c.Font = usefontgrid;
}
```

Or

```
foreach (var c in this.Controls.OfType<Label>())
{
    c.Font = usefontgrid;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Its not clear where you place this code (should be after initialize component) but try

```
foreach (Label ctl in frm.Controls.OfType<Label>())
{
    ctl.Font = usefontgrid;
}
```

There is also the following Linq to do the same thing

```
foreach (Label ctl in frm.Controls.Where(x => x is Label))
```

Comment: Note: I didn't see your last statement about how to check if the object is a label, but this will only return those controls that *are* a label

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
 foreach (Control ctl in frm.Controls)
    {
    if(ctl.GetType()==typeof(Label)){
        ctl.Font = usefontgrid;
    }
    }
```

1. frm.controls will give all controls
2. You need to check whether the control is a type of Label.