# Enable at runtime a series of serially named Label controls using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, label, controls

I have some label control named as follows :
Label1, Label2, Label3.......Label14, disabled at design time.
Now i want to enable them using a for loop in the following manner

```
for(int i=1;i<15;i++)
{
    (Label+i).Enabled = true;
}
```

Obviously the above code does not compile.

```
Label1.Enabled = true;
Label2.Enabled = true;
Label3.Enabled = true;
...........
Label14.Enabled = true;
```

Is there any other way of achieving the desired result other than the way mentioned just above.Hope i make myself clear.Please advice with code.Thanks in advance

Comment: Same answer as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481029/set-all-labels-font-before-opening-the-form just use the enabled property instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get controls by name from parent's `Controls` collection

```
for(int i = 1; i < 15; i++)
{
    Control label = this.Controls["Label"+i];
    if (label != null) 
        label.Enabled = true;
}
```

In this example `this` refers to the form. If labels belong to another parent control (e.g. Panel or GroupBox) it should be used instead of `this`

Comment: You code looks promising.However when i execute your code, it shows me an error "Object reference not set an instance of an object".Any ideas???

Comment: @gomeshmunda, please see my edit. do all labels belong to the same parent control?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your labels into a list and iterate through that list:

```
List<Label> myLabels = new List<Label> { Label1, Label2, /*...*/ Label14};
foreach(Label lbl in myLabels) lbl.Enabled = true;
```

---

If these are the only lables in your `Form` you can also do something like that:

```
foreach(Label lbl in this.Controls.OfType<Label>())
    lbl.Enabled = true;
```

This iterates through all (top level) control in your `Form` and takes all of type `Label` to set `Enabled` to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You could stick them  into an `Enumerable` and then use a `foreach` to iterate through them.

```
List<Label> lblList = new List<Label> { Label1, Label2, Label3, Label4 };

foreach (Label label in lblList)
{
    label.Enabled = true;
}
```

For a cleaner looking solution you could use the following syntax.

```
lblList.ForEach(x => x.Enabled = true);
```